# Metric units not present in Prometheus metadata

Tags: python, prometheus, metrics, exporter

I came across this issue while working on [exporter](https://github.com/mac133k/yaspex) which I wrote in Python using the [Prometheus client module](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python). Some of my custom metrics measure the memory in bytes, so I define a metric in my exporter:

```
NODES_MEM_FREE = GaugeMetricFamily('slurm_nodes_mem_free', 'Amounts of free memory allocated on nodes in the cluster ...', labels=self.labels, unit='bytes')
```

(full code [here](https://github.com/mac133k/yaspex/blob/master/nodes.py))

The unit is explicitly specified as 'bytes' which is recognized by the Prometheus client, because the metric is eventually displayed at the `/metrics` endpoint as `slurm_nodes_mem_free_bytes`. However when I check the output at `/api/v1/metadata` on my Prometheus server the unit is empty, ie.:

```
"slurm_nodes_mem_free_bytes":[{"type":"gauge","help":"Amounts of free memory allocated on nodes in the cluster grouped by cluster, partition","unit":""}]
```

First I thought there was a problem with the Python client, but then I noticed that every metric in the metadata has `"unit":""` include Prometheus internal metrics that come with the package. Is this a missing feature or maybe something with the settings on my Prometheus host?

I am using:

- Prometheus version 2.19.0, build date 20200609-10:29:59;
- Prometheus Python Client version 0.8.0.

Comment: Hmm, can you confirm via tcpdump that the openmetrics format is being negotiated for the scrape? If the Prometheus text format was negotiated, then there won't be a unit. If so, this smells like a bug.

Comment: What exactly should I be looking for in the tcpdump output? Should I set some special filters?

Comment: So far I could see `User-Agent: Prometheus/2.19.0
Accept: application/openmetrics-text; version=0.0.1,text/plain;version=0.0.4;q=0.5,*/*;q=0.1` and then the metric content followed - it looked exactly the same as in the web browser.

Comment: What was the Content-Type in the response?

Comment: `Content-Type: text/plain; version=0.0.4; charset=utf-8; charset=utf-8`

Comment: I am using `Server: gunicorn/20.0.4`.

Comment: But I can see Prometheus querying itself for metrics and returns a compressed content `Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/plain; version=0.0.4; charset=utf-8` where metrics also have no unit set as I could see in the metadata.

Comment: That's the Prometheus text format, which does not support units. Make sure you're using the latest version of both the Python client and Prometheus.

Comment: I am using `prometheus-client==0.8.0`.

Comment: @brian-brazil Is there a way to enforce OpenMetrics format, ie. by setting some params or changing the client module code?

Comment: It should be negotiated automatically,

Comment: I've just confirmed there with the latest versions that this is working correctly, so something is likey up with your setup.